# How to elegantly and imperatively generate the nth string of an alphabet?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given an alphabet such as: `["a","b","c","d"]`, the sequence of all strings made up from characters of that alphabet is:

```
""
"a"
"b"
"c"
"d"
"aa"
"ab"
"ac"
...
```

Haskell can generate the nth element of that sequence elegantly and recursively:

```
nth :: Int -> String
nth n = reverse $ alphabet !! n where
    alphabet = [""] ++ concatMap (\ str -> map (: str) "abcd") alphabet
```

But that's inefficient. Using base conversions, you could try generating it imperatively as (using JavaScript just for demonstration):

```
function nth(n) {
  var str = "";
  while (n > 0) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(97 + n % 4);
    n = Math.floor(n / 4);
  }
  return str;
};

for (var i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
  console.log(nth(i));
}
```

But that actually generates the following sequence:

```
""
"b"
"c"
"d"
"ab"
"bb"
"cb"
"db"
"ac"
"bc"
"cc"
"dc"
"ad"
"bd"
"cd"
"dd"
"aab"
```

Which is not what was desired: notice the missing "a", "aa", "ba", etc. I'm probably missing some simple operation to fixes the imperative implementation, thus, my question is: is there any elegant way to imperatively generate the nth string of an alphabet?

Comment: This Haskell code doesn't do the right thing either (and doesn't compile - use \str in lambda).

Comment: `nth :: Int -> String
nth n = reverse (alphabet !! n) where
    alphabet = [""] ++ (concatMap (\s -> map (: s) "abcd") alphabet)`

`*Main> map nth [1..30]
["a","b","c","d","aa","ab","ac","ad","ba","bb","bc","bd","ca","cb","cc","cd","da","db","dc","dd","aaa","aab","aac","aad","aba","abb","abc","abd","aca","acb"]`

Comment: @STF updated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `n--` at the beginning of the while loop. If you want the results in short lexicographic order, reverse the string before printing.

Comment: Well, I knew I was missing something simple :) how did you figure that out? I guess my brain embarrassingly crashed on this one.

Comment: I've written this code before :). To answer your question, though, I mentally stepped through some small cases and realized that -1 was the proper adjustment.